# Clojure highest 3 values of a map

Tags: clojure

Hi l'm trying to do a function that returns the 3 most commom strings

```
  (take 3 (sort-by val > (frequencies s))))

(freq ["hi" "hi" "hi" "ola" "hello" "hello" "string" "str" "ola" "hello" "hello" "str"])
```

l've got this so far but a noticed that if there are more than 1 string with the same frenquency it won't return. Is there a way to filter the values of the frequencies funcition by their highest (eventually the top 3 highest)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would propose slightly different solution which involves inverting frequencies map with `group-by` value (which is the items' count):

```
(->> data
     frequencies
     (group-by val))

;;{3 [["hi" 3]],
;; 2 [["ola" 2] ["str" 2]],
;; 4 [["hello" 4]],
;; 1 [["string" 1]]}
```

so the only thing you need is to just sort and process it:

```
(->> data
     frequencies
     (group-by val)
     (sort-by key >)
     (take 3)
     (mapv (fn [[k vs]] {:count k :items (mapv first vs)})))

;;[{:count 4, :items ["hello"]}
;; {:count 3, :items ["hi"]}
;; {:count 2, :items ["ola" "str"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`frequencies` gives you a map, where the keys are the original values to
investigate and the values in that map are the frequency of those
values.  For your result you are interested for *all* original values,
that have the most occurrences including those original values with the
same occurrences.

One way would be to "invert" the frequencies result, to get a map from
occurrences to all original values with that occurrence.  Then you can
get the highest N keys and from this map and select them (by using
a "sorted map" for inverting the map, we get the sorting by keys without
further steps).

```clj
(defn invert-map
  ([source]
   (invert-map source {}))
  ([source target]
   (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
             (update m v (fnil conj []) k))
           target
           source)))

(assert (=
         {1 ["do" "re"]}
         (invert-map {"do" 1 "re" 1})))

(defn freq
  [n s]
  (let [fs (invert-map (frequencies s) (sorted-map-by >))
        top-keys (take n (keys fs))]
    (select-keys fs top-keys)))

(assert (=
         {4 ["hello"], 3 ["hi"], 2 ["ola" "str"]}
         (freq 3 ["hi" "hi" "hi" "ola" "hello" "hello" "string" "str" "ola" "hello" "hello" "str"])))
```

Comment: `(defn invert-map [m] (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %3 %2) {} m))` - the `reduce-kv` you can use for maps.